# mod_rewrite omit html extension loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following scenario:

Two frontcontrollers in a web directory (document root):

```
web/frontend.php # handles all *.html requests
web/backend.php # direct calls only
```

Rewriting is easy so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend.php
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /frontend.php [L]
```

So now when I call `example.org/backend.php` I'm in the backend, nothing special happens. And when I call something like `example.org/` or `example.org/team/john.html` it is handled by `frontend.php`.

Works so far!

Now I want the possibility to omit the *.html extension so that `example.org/team/john` is internally handled as `example.org/team/john.html`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Last but not least I want to redirect requests to `john.html` to `john` to avoid duplicate content.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.html$
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Every part works on it's own but put together I get a loop, which doesn't surprise me but I don't know how to avoid this. I searched the docs, tried several flags and conditions but I'm totally stuck and I need help.

Here is the whole .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # extend html extension internally
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

    # redirect example.html to example
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.html$
    RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # frontcontroller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend.php
    RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /frontend.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a loop, you can use [`THE_REQUEST`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\.html "
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
```

---

Unrelated, but you can simplify your rules. First one

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend.php
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /frontend.php [L]
```

You already check for `(.+)\.html`, so you can omit the `RewriteCond`. Next, you don't use the captured part `(.+)`. Replace it with `.` to ensure it's not empty. This gives then

```
RewriteRule .\.html$ /frontend.php [L]
```

Second one, unless you have `*.html.html` files in your site, you don't need to check for `!html` and can just use `^` for the `RewriteRule` pattern

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The loop is because of the multiple internal redirections, You can use END flag to prevent the rewrite loop

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

Comment: Good, quick and helpful. Thank you! But I marked olafs answer for the extra effort.